# integrate a C and C++ program

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to control a drone using image processing.
The image capture from the drone is an opencv C++ program.
The drone control program is C program.
Now I want to integrate both the programs so that I run a single program by which I can get both images and control the drone. How do I do that?
My C program is a socket program to send commands to drone and the C++ program to capture image stream from drone from a tcp socket. 
Is there any way to do it or should I convert one whole program into another language? 
Anyone help.

regards,
shiksha

Comment: You'll probably need to either merge both programs into one program in one language or turn one (or both) of the programs into a DLL.

Comment: what OS, Environnement ?

Comment: I would compile the C program as a static lib and link it to the C++ code. To access C++ code from C, use extern "C" in the header. Don't allow any unhandled exceptions from C++ functions callable from C. You can also probably just port the C code to C++ with little effort.

Comment: i am working on linux platform

Comment: Why do you need a single program? At what point do these two independent pieces of functionality need to communicate?

Comment: i want the image grabbing an control parameters in a loop. the control parameters are fed back to stabilise the system. so i want both the programs to run in the same loop.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of options. The easiest may be to simply rename your `*.c` files to `*.cpp` - they may compile directly in C++. You may then have some issues linking with external libraries that were built using a C compiler. These linking issues can often be resolved by guarding each header include with

```
extern "C" {
    #include "header_for_c_library.h"
}
```

If this isn't feasible (e.g. if your C project consists of a lot of files, or you want to keep compiling in C), you may want to build the C part as a static library and link it with your C++ program. You could go in the other direction - build your C++ component as a static library and link it with the C program. The downside to this is that you would have to write a C wrapper for your C++ code which could take some effort (or be impossible, depending on which features of C++ you use in your API). Care must be taken to ensure the wrapper is linked as C so that the symbols will be compatible with what C produces.

Comment: System libraries generally are already protected like that.

Comment: That is true, but user-written libraries aren't always protected. It's something to be mindful of nonetheless. Particularly if his code is being run on an embedded system with sloppily written headers.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i converted my c code to cpp program. it executes fine. but when i combine both the programs it is giving a lot of errors like template with c linkage

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to compile some code which uses the C++ feature templates but are telling the compiler to use C linkage with the extern "C" trick. This post discusses it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877705/why-cant-templates-be-within-extern-c-blocks - I'd suggest seeing if you can avoid that feature in the header.

Answer (score 2):

Using C libs in C++ programs is a common way to reuse the functionality.
These languages can be built together. Usually C++ code calls C- module API which provide required functions.

In such case you can just add C files into the C++ project and build a single executable.

You only should consider the different linkage in C and C++. C function declarations should be compiled with `extern "C"` standard linkage specification. C-libraries usually already have such code in the headers (if not - add it):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" { 
#endif
```

and in the end of the file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

extern "C" prevents changing function names by C++ compiler. As C++ supports overloading, C++ compiler adds information about function parameters into the function name, so called [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). This should not be done for C-library code.