# use extern "C++" with template inside extern "C"

Tags: c++, c, linkage

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

struct A {
public:
#ifdef __cplusplus
    //extern "C++" {
    template<typename T>
    T to_string(T value) {
        return value;
    }

    //}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
};
}
int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a.to_string<int>(1);
    return 0;
}
```

How to handle situation like this to keep the main function can execute correctly?
To make struct A able to use its member function.

Since it seems unable to use `extern "C++"` in a struct and it will report error `templates must have C++ linkage` currently.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. `extern "C"` can only be used with C++, so the `#ifdef` will always be true.

Comment: I don't think you need to put this structure in `extern "C"`. It doesn't have a contrstructor, destructor, or virtual members, so it's a POD structure and should be compatible with C automatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c

Comment: Yes, you'r right. Actually this problem came from a project which may use C to call the program, I simply abstract the problem and seek for some way to make this program run successfully by modifying the code inside `extern "C"` with `#ifdef __cplusplus`.

Comment: Generally only function declarations have to be put into `extern "C"`, so that the names won't be mangled.

Comment: Removed a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877705/why-cant-templates-be-within-extern-c-blocks, the question there is different (and not answered properly). I am adding my answer there too.

Comment: A `to_string` function that returns `int`? A member function that accesses none of it's member variables? An empty struct? Looks like you simplified this code beyond the point where the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> [dcl.link](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#1) All functions and variables whose names have external linkage and all function types have a language linkage.

Class types do not. Wrapping a `struct` in `extern "C"` has no effect.

> [dcl.link](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#10) Linkage from C++ to objects defined in other languages and to objects defined in C++ from other languages is implementation-defined and language-dependent. Only where the object layout strategies of two language implementations are similar enough can such linkage be achieved.

You should just `#ifdef` out C++-specific parts of your `struct`, such as access specifications and member functions, and hope (or find in the platform documentation) that your C compiler produces a struct with the layout identical to that produced by the C++ compiler.

```
struct A {
#ifdef __cplusplus
  public:
    template<typename T>
    T to_string(T value) {
        return value;
    }
#endif /* __cplusplus */
};
```